# How to add two video filters in one command line which has transcoding done by two GPUs?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, video-streaming, decoding

I have two video filters:

> -vf "hwdownload, drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/Verdana.ttf:text='Hello World',
> format=nv12, hwupload"

and

> -vf "select='gt(scene,0.04)'" -vsync 0 'snapshot.png'

How can I add these two video filters to the below command line which does transcoding from a webcam livestream of MJPG to HEVC using two GPUs?:

> ffmpeg
> -init_hw_device cuda=decdev:/dev/dri/renderD129
> -init_hw_device vaapi=encdev:/dev/dri/renderD128
> -hwaccel cuda
> -hwaccel_device decdev
> -hwaccel_output_format cuda
> -c:v mjpeg_cuvid
> -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080
> -i /dev/video0
> -filter_hw_device encdev
> -c:v hevc_vaapi webcam.mp4"

Basically what I am trying to do is using FFMPEG to transcode and record a live webcam stream and also at the same time take snapshots when motion is detected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

NVENC does not support PNG encoding, so you must do it with CPU anyway.

How about something along the line of this:

```
ffmpeg [...] -hwaccel cuda -i /dev/video0 \
  -filter_complex \
    "hwdownload,split[ss],drawtext=[...], format=nv12, hwupload[vout];\
     [ss]select='gt(scene,0.04)'[snapshot]"\
  -map [vout] -filter_hw_device encdev -c:v hevc_vaapi webcam.mp4" \
  -map [snapshot] -vsync 0 'snapshot.png'
```

You can move the `split` filter to after the `drawtext` filter if you want to include the text.